# Does Dutch apartment electrical infrastructure support power-line communications?

Tags: netherlands, accommodation, electrical-goods, telecommunications

[Power-line communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-line_communication#PLC_Technology_Table) is a family of technologies to send data around an apartment or a building over its electrical power line. Usually we're talking about Ethernet sockets which on their other end plug into power outlets, i.e.

[image]

(The above image shows a type A plug.)

You can certainly get these devices with a Schuko plug, but would Dutch apartments typically support them well enough? I'm particularly interested in older apartments, which sometimes don't have grounding.

Comment: In Dutch ;-) these are usually called 'powerline adapters' or 'homeplug'. I find too much conflicting information about power groups and phases, old and new installations, and I'm not a electrical technician, sorry. If you can read Dutch google something like *waar moet je op letten bij lan over power*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you use them without any problem.

Some of them want an earthed/grounded plug to reach maximum speed, but without that they still work (though slower).

As for personal experience: I used a pair in a old flat (1950-ish build?) and in my parent house (1975-ish with lots of different power groups and 16 fuses. Basically one fuse per room). No problems in either location.